# LEFT JOIN 3 tables with some fields missing (NULL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 3 tables: company, address, contact, which basically contains some data on the company itself and it's address and contact info respectively. Now, not all companies have address info and contact information. I'm trying to query database to show a list of all companies: table including company's name, it's address and contact phone. So I use a query like this:

```
SELECT company.inn, company.name, company.ceo, address.city, contact.phone
    FROM company 
    JOIN address
    JOIN contact
    ON company.id = address.company_id AND company.id = contact.company_id
```

Works great but it doesn't return companies that don't have either address or contact or both. So I then tried issuing a left join command:

```
SELECT company.inn, company.name, company.ceo, address.city, contact.phone
    FROM company 
    LEFT JOIN address
    LEFT JOIN contact
    ON company.id = address.company_id AND company.id = contact.company_id
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: If you have multiple addresses and contacts, you may not get the results you expect.  If so, ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT company.inn, company.name, company.ceo, address.city, contact.phone
FROM company 
LEFT JOIN address
ON company.id = address.company_id
LEFT JOIN contact 
ON company.id = contact.company_id
```

`ON` must defined after `JOIN`. You can read the doc here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html

Comment: how do you know that?

Comment: read the doc provided, there are some good examples there @tnsaturday

Comment: I mean you read it top to bottom or just search for particular cases? It seems overwhelming to me.

Comment: do you mean found the mistake? It is quite eye catching for some peoples. Especially for someone who using it thousands or maybe millions times. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it does answer your question :)

Comment: Great many thanks for quickly answering a question in a very understandable manner!